# Accessing another salesforce org from apex class

Tags: apex, soap-api

First of all, Wish you a very happy new year. :)

I have an issue in assigning Session id while I am trying to login to another salesforce org using SOAP API. Here is the code.

```
partnerSoapSforceCom.Soap sp = new partnerSoapSforceCom.Soap();

String username = 'username';
String password = 'password';

partnerSoapSforceCom.LoginResult loginResult = sp.login(username, password);

soapSforceCom200608Apex.Apex apexWebSvc = new soapSforceCom200608Apex.Apex();
soapSforceCom200608Apex.SessionHeader_element ses = new soapSforceCom200608Apex.SessionHeader_element();
ses.SessionId = loginResult.sessionId;

apexWebSvc.timeout_x = 120000;
apexWebSvc.SessionHeader = sessionHeader;
```

I see no error in the code. But dev console throws unexpected token '=' error for every statement from `ses.SessionId = loginResult.sessionId;` statement.

Can anyone please let me know where I am missing the point.

Note. All WSDLs and apex soap api related classes are successfully generated without any compilation erros.

Answer (score 2):

```
SessionHeader.sessionId = loginResult.sessionId;
```

this should give you the session Id and set the course. Thus the code should turn out to be :

```
partnerSoapSforceCom.Soap sp = new partnerSoapSforceCom.Soap();

String username = 'username';
String password = 'password';

partnerSoapSforceCom.LoginResult loginResult = sp.login(username, password);

soapSforceCom200608Apex.Apex apexWebSvc = new soapSforceCom200608Apex.Apex();
soapSforceCom200608Apex.SessionHeader_element ses = new soapSforceCom200608Apex.SessionHeader_element();
sessionHeader.sessionId = loginResult.sessionId;
apexWebSvc.SessionHeader = sessionHeader;
```

Comment: Amit -- you might want to clean up your answer and eliminate those `<br/>` to avoid confusing some apex newbie

Comment: I removed the br tags - couldn't stand looking at them ;-)